# jsRender and node.js

Tags: node.js, jsrender

I am a complete beginner with node.js.

What I try to do is to parse a jsrender template on server side

I donwloaded jsrender.js from [git](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/jsrender.js)

this is my attempt ... saved as render.js:

```
var data = [
    {id:1, name:"tom"},
    {id:2, name:"jack"},
]

require('./jsrender.js', function(jsrender){
    console.log('test');
    var result = jsrender.render['<p>{{:id}} <b>{{:name}}</p>']( data );
    console.log(result);
} );
```

and then runned it (node render.js)

and I get NOTHING

what am I doing wrong?

======================================================

tried this way too:

```
 var data = [
    {id:1, name:"tom"},
    {id:2, name:"jack"},
]
var jsrender = require('./jsrender.js');

var result = jsrender.render('<p>{{:id}} <b>{{:name}}</p>',data );
console.log(result);
```

and I am getting

```
var result = jsrender.render('<p>{{:id}} <b>{{:name}}</p>',data );
                      ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'render'
```

========================================================================

tried also installing this [node_jsrender module](http://geekple.com/nodejs/node_jsrender)

and this syntax:

```
var jsrender = require('./jsrender');

process.on('start', function () {
  jsrender.template("yourtemplate", "{{:myvar}}");
  var result = jsrender.render("yourtemplate", {myvar:"Hello World!"});

  console.log(result);
});
```

ALSO EMPTY result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first you need to install the Node.js module.

```
npm install node_jsrender
```

This will create a node_modules directory with node_jsrender directory inside. Next you need to require.

```
var jsrender = require('node_jsrender');
```

If the first parameters of the require method starts with `./` it means that you want to import a local file. Without it Node.js will look at the node_modules directory.

```
jsrender.template("yourtemplate", "{{=myvar}}");
var result = jsrender.render("yourtemplate", {myvar:"Hello World!"});
```

I checked the syntax of that template engine and it's `{{=` and not `{{:`?

Comment: I've seen it using with anonymous callback way... but anyway... even if I do it like in the second version, I get an error that render is not a method of jsrender

Comment: Can't fint it anymore... ok I did as you suggested. I installed the module npm install node_js_render (on windows in the directory where node.js was installed, and it shows with all the sources in the node_modules directory).... then I did as you suggested in my script... and I am getting the error: Error: Cannot find module './jsrender'